goal state never achieved in DQN model
I have a problem where I have this DQN code that interacts with python.exe and sends a sequence of characters that when reaching 14 characters will be flushed or sent and proccesed by python, and if it correctly inputs the characters in order, it gets rewarded. I even increased the neuron + hidden layers considerably (around 10000 neurons 1 time and 6 hidden layers) and I know that the depth and width aren't the problem, and so now I am stuck as to why I can never reach the goal state
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple, deque
from itertools import count
import subprocess
import select

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

class ExternalProgramEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, program_path):
        super(ExternalProgramEnv, self).__init__()
        self.program_path = program_path
        self.observation_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([256] * 14)  # Current input sequence (string)
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(6)  # 12 actions corresponding to characters
        self.goal_state = 'print("hello")'
        self.input_sequence = ''  # Initialize input sequence

    def step(self, action):
        self.input_sequence += self._action_to_char(action)
        
        if len(self.input_sequence) >= 14:  # Check if input sequence length reaches 14 characters
            output = self._execute_input_sequence()  # Send the input sequence for execution
            reward = self._calculate_reward(output, action)
            done = self._is_done(output)
            observation = self.input_sequence  # Set observation to input sequence
            return observation, reward, done, {}
        else:
            return self.input_sequence, 0, False, {}

    def reset(self):
        self.input_sequence = ''  # Reset input sequence
        return self.input_sequence

    def _execute_input_sequence(self):
        try:
            print("Input to external program:", self.input_sequence)
            proc = subprocess.Popen(self.program_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)  # Removed extra parenthesis
            stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input=self.input_sequence, timeout=0.1)
            if stderr:
                print("Error while providing input:", stderr)
                print("Output from external program:", stdout)
            self.input_sequence = ''  # Reset the input sequence after execution
            return stdout.strip()
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print("Timeout expired while providing input.")
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e)
            return None

    def _action_to_char(self, action):
        actions_mapping = {0: 'pr', 1: 'i', 2: 'n', 3: 't', 4: '("hell', 5: 'o")'} 
        return actions_mapping[action]

    def _calculate_reward(self, output, action):
        reward = 0.0

    # Reward for matching characters
        for i in range(min(len(output), len(self.goal_state))):
            if output[i] == self.goal_state[i]:
                reward += 5.0  # Reward for each matching character

        # Bonus reward for correct position in the sequence
        if len(self.input_sequence) >= 14 and action < len(self.goal_state):
            reward += 10.0

        return reward  # Moved inside the function



    def _is_done(self, output):
        return output == self.goal_state

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program_path = r"C:\Users\andye\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"
    env = ExternalProgramEnv(program_path)

# set up matplotlib
is_ipython = 'inline' in matplotlib.get_backend()
if is_ipython:
    from IPython import display

plt.ion()

# if GPU is to be used
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

Transition = namedtuple('Transition', ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward'))

class ReplayMemory(object):
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.memory = deque([], maxlen=capacity)

    def push(self, *args):
        """Save a transition"""
        state, action, next_state, reward = args
        # Encode string observations into one-hot tensors
        state_encoded = torch.zeros(1, 14, dtype=torch.long, device=device)  # Adjust the size to match the observation space
        next_state_encoded = torch.zeros(1, 14, dtype=torch.long, device=device)  # Adjust the size to match the observation space
        for i, char in enumerate(state):
            state_encoded[0][i] = ord(char)
        for i, char in enumerate(next_state):
            next_state_encoded[0][i] = ord(char)
        self.memory.append(Transition(state_encoded, action, next_state_encoded, reward))

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)

class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_observations, n_actions):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(256, 10)  # Embedding layer to handle characters
        embedding_size = 10  # Dimension of the embedding
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(embedding_size * 14, 5100)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(5100, 5100)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(5100, 5100)
        self.layer4 = nn.Linear(5100, n_actions)  # Adjust input size to match output size of layer2

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x)  # Embedding the input characters
        if x.size(1) == 0:
            return torch.zeros(x.size(0), self.layer4.out_features, device=x.device)  # Return zeros if input is empty
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten the embedding
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer3(x))
        return self.layer4(x)

BATCH_SIZE = 345
GAMMA = 1.0
EPS_START = 0.75
EPS_END = 0.03
EPS_DECAY = 1000
TAU = 0.005
LR = 1e-4

# Initialize the environment
env.reset()

# Get number of observations and actions from the environment
n_observations = env.observation_space.shape[0]  # Use shape instead of n
n_actions = env.action_space.n

# Initialize DQN
policy_net = DQN(n_observations, n_actions).to(device)
target_net = DQN(n_observations, n_actions).to(device)
target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())
target_net.eval()

# Initialize the optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam(policy_net.parameters(), lr=LR)

# Initialize replay memory
memory = ReplayMemory(10000)

# Initialize some variables for training
steps_done = 0
episode_durations = []

# Define epsilon-greedy action selection function
def select_action(state):
    global steps_done
    sample = random.random()
    eps_threshold = EPS_END + (EPS_START - EPS_END) * math.exp(-1.0 * steps_done / EPS_DECAY)
    steps_done += 1
    
    # Encode string observation into one-hot tensor
    state_encoded = torch.zeros(1, 14, dtype=torch.long, device=device)  # Adjust the size to match the observation space
    for i, char in enumerate(state):
        state_encoded[0][i] = ord(char)
    
    if sample > eps_threshold:
        with torch.no_grad():
            return policy_net(state_encoded).max(1)[1].view(1, 1)
    else:
        return torch.tensor([[random.randrange(n_actions)]], device=device, dtype=torch.long)

# Define function to optimize the model
def optimize_model():
    if len(memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
        return
    transitions = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
    batch = Transition(*zip(*transitions))
    non_final_mask = torch.tensor(tuple(map(lambda s: s is not None, batch.next_state)), device=device, dtype=torch.bool)
    non_final_next_states = torch.cat([s for s in batch.next_state if s is not None])
    state_batch = torch.cat(batch.state)
    action_batch = torch.cat(batch.action)
    reward_batch = torch.cat(batch.reward)

    state_action_values = policy_net(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)

    next_state_values = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE, device=device, requires_grad=True)  # Set requires_grad to True
    next_state_values = torch.where(non_final_mask.unsqueeze(1), target_net(non_final_next_states).max(1)[0], next_state_values)
    expected_state_action_values = (next_state_values * GAMMA) + reward_batch

    # Ensure the shapes are consistent by squeezing the unnecessary dimension
    state_action_values = state_action_values.squeeze(1)
    expected_state_action_values = expected_state_action_values.squeeze(1)

    loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(state_action_values, expected_state_action_values)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    
    # Update only the parameters that require gradients
    optimizer.step()

    # Plot rewards per episode
    if episode_rewards:  # Check if episode_rewards is not empty
        plt.plot(range(i_episode + 1), episode_rewards, color='b')
    plt.xlabel('Episodes')
    plt.ylabel('Total Reward')
    plt.title('Rewards per Episode')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.pause(0.001)  # Pause to allow the plot to update

# Training loop
num_episodes = 700
episode_rewards = []  # List to store rewards per episode
plt.figure()  # Create a single figure for plotting

for i_episode in range(num_episodes):
    # Initialize the environment and state
    state = env.reset()
    total_reward = 0  # Initialize total reward for this episode
    actions_taken = []  # List to store actions taken
    
    for t in count():
        # Select and perform an action
        action = select_action(state)
        actions_taken.append(action.item())  # Store the action taken
        
        # Get Q-values for all actions in the current state
        state_encoded = torch.zeros(1, 14, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
        for i, char in enumerate(state):
            state_encoded[0][i] = ord(char)
        q_values = policy_net(state_encoded)
        if len(state) > 0:  # Check if the state string is not empty
            print("Q-values for state {}: {}".format(state, q_values.squeeze().detach().cpu().numpy()))
        
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action.item())
        reward = torch.tensor([reward], device=device)
        
        # Update total reward
        total_reward += reward.item()

        # Store the transition in memory
        memory.push(state, action, next_state, reward)

        # Move to the next state
        state = next_state

        # Perform one step of the optimization (on the target network)
        optimize_model()
        
        # Check if the goal state is reached
        if done:
            print("Goal reached!")
            break
    
    # Append total reward for this episode to the list
    episode_rewards.append(total_reward)

    # Update the target network
    if i_episode % TAU == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())

    # Print actions if the goal state is reached
    if env._is_done():
        print("Actions taken to reach goal state:", actions_taken)
        break  # Stop training loop if the goal state is reached

# Close the environment
env.close()







And as I explained I did try to solve it by adjusting the architecture, but it seems that isn't the problem, I already tried with a different algorithm, same story
